# 12v coolant pump powered from leisure battery and starter battery. HOW?

Tags: battery, motorhome

OK so I am trying to figure out final component of my camper electrical system and I have found I am stepping beyond the scope of "connect A to B" etc.

I have a diesel water heater with an auxillary pump (12v) which circulates hot water to where I need it. This comes with a wiring loom which will be connected to the leasure battery bank so can be brought on and off using the supplied controller. This is fine. HOWEVER, what I would like to do is run that same pump from the starter battery when the engine is running. My plan was to just connect a cable to the pump however I'm starting to read things about Diodes, surge protection, filtering and Relays which has made me want some advice.

I understand the concept that a diode will stop the feeding of 1 into the other. But googling for such diodes has left me thinking there's still lots I don't know.

Can anyone explain what may be best way or how to approach buying the right thing. Ideally there is a product out there which I can just splice in with both supplies and the load. But I don't want to buy the wrong thing or bodge something together that causes problems down the line.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think what you're looking for is an isolator system which will charge both the starter battery and the leisure battery at the same time, but only allows power for starting to be drawn from the main battery and the pump would run exclusively off the leisure battery. Also, all diodes do is only allow power to run in one direction. It can be used for several things, but mainly prevents electricity from flowing back through the system and powering stuff you don't want it to.

Comment: Is your leisure battery being charged when the engine is running? If so, you don't need to do anything as the leisure battery will be kept charged already. If not, why not solve that and give yourself more flexibility?